# multi-type operation function in C

Tags: c

I'm writing a function which just make the sum of two values,

but the C type of these values is specified in parameter,

it can be int, unsigned int, char, unsigned char, float ...

I search a solution to do that without making a lot of C code to process to all different mixed cases.

To be clear the code is :

```
void addition(unsigned char type_data_1_uc, void *value_data_1_ptr, 
              unsigned char type_data_2_uc, void *value_data_2_ptr, 
          unsigned char type_result_uc, void *value_result_ptr)
{

    /* types :
       0 : TYPE_BIT
       1 : TYPE_CHAR 
       2 : TYPE_UNSIGNED_CHAR
       3 : TYPE_INT
       4 : TYPE_UNSIGNED_INT
       5 : TYPE_SHORT_INT
       6 : TYPE_UNSIGNED_SHORT_INT
       7 : TYPE_LONG
       8 : TYPE_UNSIGNED_LONG
       9 : TYPE_FLOAT */

    /* INT + INT = INT */
    if ((type_data_1_uc == 3)
     && (type_data_2_uc == 3)
     && (type_result_uc == 3))
    {
     *((int *) value_result_ptr) = *((int *) value_data_1_ptr) + *((int *) value_data_2_ptr);
    }

    /* FLOAT + FLOAT = FLOAT */
    if ((type_data_1_uc == 9)
     && (type_data_2_uc == 9)
     && (type_result_uc == 9))
    {
     *((float *) value_result_ptr) = *((int *) value_data_1_ptr) + *((int *) value_data_2_ptr);
    }

    /* UNSIGNED CHAR + INT = INT */
    if ((type_data_1_uc == 2)
     && (type_data_2_uc == 3)
     && (type_result_uc == 3))
    {
     *((int *) value_result_ptr) = *((unsigned char *) value_data_1_ptr) + *((int *) value_data_2_ptr);
    }

    /* ......... */

}


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

    int data_1;
    int data_2;
    int result;

    data_1 = 26;
    data_2 = 32;


    addition(3, &data_1, 3, &data_2, 3, &result);

    printf("result = %d\n", result);

    return 0;   

}
```

I have think to use the union structure but it doesn't solve the problem, because union also need to be statically casted :

```
/* UNION DATA */
union data_union 
{
    char tab_c[4];
    unsigned char tab_uc[4];
    int i;
    unsigned int ui;
    short int si;
    unsigned short int usi;
    long l;
    unsigned long ul;
    float f;
};


void addition(unsigned char type_data_1_uc, union data_union *value_data_1_ptr, 
              unsigned char type_data_2_uc, union data_union *value_data_2_ptr, 
          unsigned char type_result_uc, union data_union *value_result_ptr)
{

    /* types :
       0 : TYPE_BIT
       1 : TYPE_CHAR 
       2 : TYPE_UNSIGNED_CHAR
       3 : TYPE_INT
       4 : TYPE_UNSIGNED_INT
       5 : TYPE_SHORT_INT
       6 : TYPE_UNSIGNED_SHORT_INT
       7 : TYPE_LONG
       8 : TYPE_UNSIGNED_LONG
       9 : TYPE_FLOAT */


        /* INT + INT = INT */
        if ((type_data_1_uc == 3)
         && (type_data_2_uc == 3)
         && (type_result_uc == 3))
        {
         (*value_result_ptr).i = (*value_data_1_ptr).i + (*value_data_2_ptr).i;
        }

        /* FLOAT + FLOAT = FLOAT */
        if ((type_data_1_uc == 9)
         && (type_data_2_uc == 9)
         && (type_result_uc == 9))
        {
         (*value_result_ptr).f = (*value_data_1_ptr).f + (*value_data_2_ptr).f;
        }

        /* UNSIGNED CHAR + INT = INT */
        if ((type_data_1_uc == 2)
         && (type_data_2_uc == 3)
         && (type_result_uc == 3))
        {
         (*value_result_ptr).i = (*value_data_1_ptr).uc + (*value_data_2_ptr).i;
        }

}


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

    static union data_union data_1_union;
    static union data_union data_2_union;
    static union data_union result_union;

    memset(&data_1_union, 0, sizeof(union data_union));
    memset(&data_2_union, 0, sizeof(union data_union));

    data_1_union.i = 26;
    data_2_union.i = 32;


    addition(3, &data_1_union, 3, &data_2_union, 3, &result_union);

    printf("result_union.i = %d\n", result_union.i);

    return 0;   

}
```

Any idea to solve this ?

Comment: What is the use case? Why don't you simply write a function `add(long long, long long)` and handle float cases somehow?

Comment: This weird, what's the purpose of this ? Is this a real world problem or just academic ?

Comment: I think you should analyze your requirement.

Comment: Yes it's a real world problem, my values are initialy in database, i get them and stock in union with many types, and after i have to do some calculs between them

Answer (score 4):

You cannot do that without some "pain", since C is statically typed language. The compiler needs to know the types of variables in order to generate the proper instructions. Most CPU:s have distinct instructions for adding 8-bit integers, 32-bit integers, floats, and so on.

That said, you can certainly improve on the interface: I would use variable arguments to make the prototype:

```
typedef enum {
  TYPE_BIT = 0,
  TYPE_CHAR,
  TYPE_UNSIGNED_CHAR,
  TYPE_INT,
  TYPE_UNSIGNED_INT,
  TYPE_SHORT_INT,
  TYPE_UNSIGNED_SHORT_INT,
  TYPE_LONG,
  TYPE_UNSIGNED_LONG,
  TYPE_FLOAT,
} Type;

void addition(Type type, void *result, ...);
```

This expects to be called with four arguments, the two latter of which should have the type indicated by the `type` argument. The result is stored at `result`, which should be a pointer to the same type as the arguments.

Not sure how to represent single-bit values, probably as `unsigned char` but it's kind of pointless: single bits is not a type that you can do arithmetic with in C so you're just going to end up doing the add with more bits, then masking some of them off. You also can't have a pointer to a single bit in memory on most machines.

Answer (score 0):

The idiomatic C approach to this problem is to use macros to eliminate code duplication as much as possible. The rest will unfortunately have to be done manually. For example:

```
enum typecode {
  TC_INT = 3,
  TC_FLOAT = 9,
  /* ... */
};

void addition(enum typecode type_data_1_uc, void *value_data_1_ptr, 
              enum typecode type_data_2_uc, void *value_data_2_ptr, 
              enum typecode type_result_uc, void *value_result_ptr)
{
#define DO_ADD(tc1, tc2, tcret, type1, type2, typeret) do {        \
  if (type_data_1_uc == tc1 && type_data_2_uc == tc2               \
      && type_result_uc == tcret) {                                \
    *(typeret *)value_result_ptr =                                 \
       *(type1 *)(value_data_1_ptr) + *(type2 *)(value_data_2_ptr) \
    return;                                                        \
  } while (0)

  /* INT + INT = INT */
  DO_ADD(TC_INT, TC_INT, TC_INT, int, int, int);
  /* FLOAT + FLOAT = FLOAT */
  DO_ADD(TC_FLOAT, TC_FLOAT, TC_FLOAT, float, float, float);
  /* UCHAR + INT = INT */
  DO_ADD(TC_UCHAR, TC_INT, TC_INT, unsigned char, int, int);
  /* ... */

#undef DO_ADD

  /* none matched: abort() or set an error code, as appropriate */
}
```

Comment: Nice, this code work, however it need one DO_ADD by mixed operation.

Comment: @user3114142 Sorry, I don't understand your comment. What do you mean by mixed operation? The third invocation, `UCHAR + INT = INT`, was supposed to cover the case of mixed argument types, if that's what you are referring to.